# convert custom locale date time to gmt in android

Tags: android

I am trying to convert this date time format which was created on locale time on android device to GMT . I am unable to get the right value .Also the dateTime generated is for the local time on android.How can I convert it to exact GMT unixtime ?

```
         String dateTime="02-02-2016 8:28 PM";
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
            format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = format.parse(dateTime);
                System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long unixtime = date.getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try{
                    SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    Log.v("Current time", ""+ sourceFormat.format(new Date()));

                    Date parsed = sourceFormat.parse(sourceFormat.format(new Date())); // => Date is in UTC now


                    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
                    SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

//                  String result = destFormat.format(parsed);
                    String result = destFormat.format(sourceFormat.parse(sourceFormat.format(new Date())));

                    Log.e("result", ""+result);


//                  2015-11-26 02:07:59                 
                    SimpleDateFormat UTCFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    SimpleDateFormat severFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    SimpleDateFormat localFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                    UTCFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                    TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
                    severFormat.setTimeZone(tz1);

                    localFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

                    Date serverDate = severFormat.parse(result);
                    Date utcDate =  UTCFormat.parse(UTCFormat.format(serverDate));

                    String localDate = localFormat.format(utcDate);
                    Log.e("localDate", ""+localDate);
                }catch(ParseException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please convert the string I have created. I am not taking the current date and time also each device will have its own timezone.

Comment: I think you can do that. If there is any problem then ask me.

Comment: Above solution have convert to specifi timezone and specific timezone to local date

Comment: I am using 
        int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings(); and 
        long unixtime = (date.getTime() -(gmtOffset))/1000;
        Log.w("unixtime",unixtime+""); and it works for now.